# 2 values inside an if statement C#

Tags: c#

IT SHOULD NORMALLY COMPUTE FOR BLOOD PRESSURE AT GIVEN RANGES OF SYSTOLIC AND DIASTOLIC VALUES

```
        private void txtBPDiastolic_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int systolic, diastolic;
            systolic = int.Parse(txtBPSystolic.Text);
            diastolic = int.Parse(txtBPDiastolic.Text);
            if (systolic <= 120)
            {
                if (diastolic <= 80)
                {
                    txtbpStat.Text = "Normal";
                }

            }

            else if (systolic < 120 && systolic >= 129)
            {
                if (diastolic < 80)
                {
                    txtbpStat.Text = "Elevated";
                }

            }

            else if (systolic <= 130 && systolic >= 139 )
            {
                if (diastolic <= 80 && diastolic >= 89)
                {
                    txtbpStat.Text = "Highblood (Stage1)";
                }

            }

            else if (systolic >= 140)
            {
                if (diastolic >= 90)
                {
                    txtbpStat.Text = "Highblood (Stage2)";
                }

            }

            else if (systolic > 180)
            {
                if (diastolic > 120)
                {
                    txtbpStat.Text = "Hypertensive Crisis";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Input Valid values");
        }
    }
```

I HAVE 2 VARIABLES INSIDE THE IF STATEMENT AND I CANNOT SEEM TO BE COMPUTED PROPERLY

IT CANNOT READ OTHER RESULTS THAN 'NORMAL' and ignores the remaining options for results

Comment: Your caps-lock key is stuck.

Comment: Also, this is funny (perhaps): `systolic < 120 && systolic >= 129` or this `systolic <= 130 && systolic >= 139` or `diastolic <= 80 && diastolic >= 89`. Please make an effort in trying to understand what you have written here...

Comment: ***PLEASE STOP YELLING AT US!*** Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's very hard to read, and it's generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, which is just plain rude - **don't do it** and fix your post here ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

Take a careful look at the conditions in your `if` statements, as many of them are impossible to meet. For example, the second condition:

```
else if (systolic < 120 && systolic >= 129)
```

A value cannot be both less than 120 and greater than 129 simultaneously, so this condition will never return `true`.

The second `if` statement in many of these checks means that even if the systolic reading satisfies the condition, the diastolic may not, meaning the status is never changed (e.g., sys 150, dia 85).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems here:
1) Your <= and >= needs to be reversed in each of the if statements.
2) The last else clause will never be reached because the else if above it will be met.
3) Nested if's should be combined.  You may meet the outer but not the inner and do nothing, or you may meet the inner but not the outer and print the wrong thing.